# Building mozilla on solaris

Tags: solaris, mozilla, solaris-studio

Running 'mach build' on SunOS 11.2, configure fails in the obj-i386-pc-solaris2.11/intl/icu/target directory, claiming the C compiler can't make executables, because cc is being invoked with what appears to be a MS compiler flag, '-MD'. Even thought I am running 'mach' with CC and SOLARIS_SUNPRO_CC set to 'cc', CXX and SOLARIS_SUNPRO_CXX set to 'CC' in the environment, this flag seems to be coming from RTL_FLAGS in config/config.mk; but by rights it shouldn't be happening because of the 'ifeq' around it.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this please?

Comment: Dump all the predefined compiler macros with `cc -xdumpmacros -E /dev/null`.  Run that in same environment.  Maybe the build process is picking up on something else.  (Dumping predefined macros for all major compilers:  http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros)

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion but it doesn't work. I have resorted to editing the configure scripts and putting in the right flags at the point where they are needed. Autoconf is a nightmare when it doesn't work and it often doesn't, especially if you aren't working on the Microsoft-of-the-Unix world, namely, Linux.